# desactivar la selección de asientos comprados en autobús

Tags: java, android-studio, select, multiselect, confirmar

por favor ruego que me ayudéis,soy nueva.
lo comento:
estoy haciendo una app de venta de billetes de autobuses , no logro desactivar la selección de los asientos comprados después del pago(hacerlo invisible o de otro color menteniendo la misma posición de los items).
la activity del pago es distinta a la activity de selección de asientos.
lo dejo el código.
el lenguaje utilizado es java y la plataforma es Android studio

mi Adapter:

```
 public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    static Context context;
    //TextView textV;

    LayoutInflater inflater;
     public static List<Item> items;
    List<Item> selected;
    OnClickAction receiver;




    public  interface OnClickAction {

          void onClickAction();
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        // TextView tv;
        CardView cardView;
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        public static TextView textV;


        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            textV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textV);
        }
    }

    public ItemAdapter(Context context) {

        //this.textV = textV;
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.selected = new ArrayList<>();
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.siege_principal, parent, false);

        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }




    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Item item = items.get(position);

        RecyclerViewHolder.textV.setText(items.get(position).getTextV());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(items.get(position).getSieges());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            if (selected.contains(item )) {

                 selected.remove(item);

   
                unhighlightView(holder);

            }

            else {
                selected.add(item);
              
                highlightView(holder);

            }


           

            receiver.onClickAction();

        });

        if (selected.contains(item)) {

            highlightView(holder);
        }


        else {
            unhighlightView(holder);
       }
    }

   
    private void highlightView(RecyclerViewHolder holder) {

         holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected));


    }

    private void unhighlightView(RecyclerViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent));
    }
    private void anotherhighlightView(RecyclerViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_red_light));
    }
    private void chauffeurhighlightView(RecyclerViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
    }
    public static void removeLightView(RecyclerViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.black));
    }

    @Override
    public  int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void addAll(List<Item> items) {
        clearAll(false);
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

     
    }

    public void clearAll(boolean isNotify) {
        items.clear();
        selected.clear();
        if (isNotify) notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

     public  void clearSelected() {


        selected.clear();
       // items.remove(selected);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

   /* public  void removehithlightView(){
        //selected.remove(items.size());
        //selected.set()

        if(selected.contains(items )) {
            RecyclerViewHolder.textV.setEnabled(true);
            removeLightView();


            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }*/
   /* public  void removeAt(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        items.remove(items.get(items.indexOf(selected)));

        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, items.size());
    }

   /* public static void removeItemAtPosition(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
    }*/


    public void selectAll() {
        selected.clear();
        selected.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
   /* public void unSeletectItem(){

        selected.isEmpty();
        items.isEmpty();


    }*/
  /*º    public  void setSelected(){
        if (items.toString().startsWith("00")){
            clearSelected();
        }
   }*/

    public List<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public List<Item> setSelected(){
        return selected;

    }

    public void setActionModeReceiver(OnClickAction receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }



    public static class Item {
        private  int sieges;
        // private int imag;
        private String textVs;


        public int getSieges() {
            return sieges;
        }

        public void setSieges(int sieges) {
            this.sieges = sieges;
        }

        public String getTextV() {
            return textVs;
        }

        public Predicate<? super Item> setTextV(String textVs) {
            this.textVs = textVs;
            return null;
        }

        public Item(int sieges, String textVs) {
            this.sieges = sieges;
            this.textVs = textVs;
        }
    }
}
```

Mi Activity java

```
public class SiegeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickAction {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public  static  RecyclerViewHolder holder;

    // static int selected;
     static String items;
    static int qteSieges;
    public static int selected;
    //public static ItemAdapter.Item unSelectecItem;

    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

    Activity activity = SiegeActivity.this;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    ActionMode actionMode;

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static  TextView textPrix;

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static TextView textView;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static TextView textView2;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static TextView textSetSelection;
    Button btnDeSelected, btnSelectedAll, btnValidezSiege;


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.cab_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_email:
                    Toast.makeText(activity, itemAdapter.getSelected().size() + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            actionMode = null;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_siege);


        textSetSelection = findViewById(R.id.textSetSelection);


        textPrix = findViewById(R.id.textPrix);

        nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

        btnDeSelected = findViewById(R.id.btnDeSelected);
        btnSelectedAll = findViewById(R.id.btnSelectedAll);
        btnValidezSiege = findViewById(R.id.btnValidezSiege);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //textV = findViewById(R.id.textV);


        

        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 15);
        recycler = findViewById(R.id.rvView);
        recycler.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

       
     
        btnValidezSiege.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SiegeActivity.this, EnregistrementActivity.class);


                startActivity(intent);


            }



        });

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();


        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.sieges, "01"));
        .............................................
        .............................................
    
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.sieges, "41"));
        .............................................
        .............................................


        itemAdapter.addAll(items);
        itemAdapter.setActionModeReceiver((OnClickAction) activity);
        // textView.setText(("Sieges:" + items.get(Item).getTextV().toString()));

       /* if (selected == itemAdapter.getSelected().size()) {
            RecyclerViewHolder.textV.setEnabled(true);
            removeLightView(holder);
            // setVisible(false);
            //return;
        }*/

    }

    // @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void selectAll(View v) {
        itemAdapter.selectAll();
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = startActionMode(actionModeCallback);

            //actionMode.setType(Integer.parseInt("Selected: " + adapter.getSelected().size()));
            actionMode.setTitle(getString(R.string.Nombre_de_billets_) + itemAdapter.getSelected().size());
        }
    }

    public void deselectAll(View v) {
        itemAdapter.clearSelected();
        if (actionMode != null) {
            actionMode.finish();
            actionMode = null;

        }
    }



    public void onClickAction() {

       selected = itemAdapter.getSelected().size();


        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = startActionMode(actionModeCallback);

            actionMode.setTitle(getString(R.string.Nombre_de_billets_) + "" + itemAdapter.getSelected().size());

            //textSetSelection.setText(String.valueOf(selected));
            textSetSelection.setText(textSetSelection.getText().toString());


        } else {
            if (selected == 0) {
                actionMode.finish();


            } else {


                actionMode.setTitle(getString(R.string.Nombre_de_billets_) + "" + itemAdapter.getSelected().size());
                //textSetSelection.setText(String.valueOf(selected));
                textSetSelection.setText((getString(R.string.Nombre_de_billets_) + itemAdapter.getSelected().size()));
                textSetSelection.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }

        }

    }
   
}
```

aquí la Activity siguiente a la  de confirmación de pago,donde quiero desactivar la selección ,confirmado así la plaza reservada.

```
public class ConcatenationCarteTaxiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 
    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    Button btnConfirmationDoneesAchats, btnDechargeTicket;


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static TextView textViewPrincipal;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static TextView  textView3,textView4,textView5;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_concatenacion);




        nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
        textViewPrincipal = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView3 =  findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4 =  findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView5 =  findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        btnDechargeTicket = findViewById(R.id.btnDechargeTicket);

        btnConfirmationDoneesAchats = findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmationDoneesAchats);

        btnConfirmationDoneesAchats.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ConcatenationCarteTaxiActivity.this, ImpressionNomsVoyageursTaxiActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        });
```